# Why is fgets() not accepting any input in this case?

Tags: c, fgets

This code will work fine if I use `fgets()` first and then `scanf()`,but not the other way around. Why?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main(void) 
{
    int n;
    char a[100];

    scanf("%d",&n);                  //accept a number from user
    fgets(a,100*sizeof(char),stdin); //accept a string from user

    printf("%d\n",2*n);
    printf("%s\n",a);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: (1) you have to consume the trailing newline from `stdin` buffer before calling `fgets`. (2) You don't need `sizeof(char)` in `fgets`, it equals `1`. Please, have a look at [this SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14565956/how-to-get-newline-character-from-scanf-even-if-its-the-only-input).

Comment: Add a `getchar()` after `scanf` to consume the newline and you're good. The `sizeof(char)` is ok, it makes the intention clear.

Comment: @artm, thanks for the comment. I didn't mean `sizeof(char)` was wrong, just _extraneous_, because `fgets()` reads characters so and so, which makes the code unnecessarily verbose.

Comment: @user3078414 `fgets(a, sizeof(a), stdin);` is better I suppose..

Comment: Of course @artm, `sizeof(a)` is the best, because it is most maintainable! (-: