# How to get newline sign using scanf?

Tags: c, scanf

I am trying to create a simple notepad-like program to type in command prompt. But can't exactly get to the next line by pressing "Enter" using scanf() function.

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main ()
{
char c;
for(;;){
        scanf("%c", &c);
   if(c == "\n"){
        printf("\n");
        }
   else{
        printf("%c", c);
        }
}
}
```

(I know scanf() leaves the new char in buffer. I have tried my best to get rid of the problem. Used getch() function after than scanf() but I can't make it work. I have to understand this issue with the scanf() function so I would like to avoid alternatives like using string or something else)

Comment: `"\n"` is a string (containing one character), `'\n'` is a character

Comment: You mean to say your compiler din't warn you, or you chose to ignore that? Tell me something, showing up in SO, writing up a question, posting it, waiting for _answers_, is it really _too much fun_?

Comment: You seem to be misunderstanding what `scanf` does. It does *not* leave the characters it extracts in the buffer. What would be the purpose of that?

Comment: Yes it did show a warning "warning: comparison between pointer and integer" but sorry I am a newbie in programming. I couldn't understand what it meant so I just ignored it. Would you please explain the warning? What is pointer? @SouravGhosh

Comment: @FarhanFuad _"What is pointer"_ if that is your question, **Immediately** go and read a C book. don't try to write code straightaway.

Comment: If you are suggesting me to use ''\n'' instead of '"\n"' then it's not working @immibis

Comment: Also for performance reasons, don't use `scanf` to read characters. Declare `c` as an `int` and just `fgetc` instead. Remember to check for `EOF` as well (where declaring the variable as `int` comes into play).

Comment: Lastly, if all you want is to do is print a newline when you have read a newline, you don't need the `if` statement. Printing `c` will print a newline if `c` is a newline.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, you're a little bit unfortunate. This is a popular issue at the beggining of C programming. In `C` there is a huge difference between `'\n'` and `"n"`. The first one is single character, so the type of `'\n'` is `char`. The other one is a string, and strings in `C` are `char[]`s. It means that actually `"\n" = ['\n', '\0']` as strings are terminated with `'\0'` in `C`.

Another thing is, that `scanf` ignores leading white signs and a new line is a white sign. If you want to get more characters use `fgets` instead. For reading single characted, scanf is still ok.

This was widely described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14565956/how-to-get-newline-character-from-scanf-even-if-its-the-only-input) stack overflow topic.

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main () {
    char c;
    for(;;){
        scanf("%c", &c);
       if(c == '\n'){
           printf("\n");
       } else{
             printf("%c", c);
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that for the `"%c"` format then `scanf` doesn't skip whitespace.

Comment: Umm it's still not working in my pc. Have you checked?

Comment: @FarhanFuad Yes, I did. Did you copy/paste or rewrite? Did you recompile? Do you have exactly the same printf as I?

Comment: Yes I copy pasted. say, I typed "hello" then when I press enter another "hello" is printed on the next line and the cursor gets to the line after that

Comment: So it's exactly as you have described the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think it will be better to use `getch()` to achieve whatever your trying to achieve.

```
while(1){
  int i = getch();
  if(i==13) printf("\n");
  // [Maybe an else if ladder for different shortcuts/keys...]
  else printf("%c",i);
}
```

I know I am late, but I hope this this answer benefits anyone who reads it in the future.